# How to calculate cycles per byte

Tags: performance

Sometimes, websites and scientific papers that introduce and/or handle cryptographic algorithms also provide speed-analysis and tables comparing the individual performance of cryptographic implementations. I would like to do the same, but I'm not sure how to calculate the “cycles”.

I have this data:

- processor clock frequency: **2,1 ghz**
- message length: **16 byte**
- Speed: **4,3 Mbytes/s**

How can I calculate “cycles” and “cycles per byte” from that data?

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE! Please note that this question is [off-topic](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/faq), and in general the community expects someone to do [some research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle) before asking a question.

Comment: I'm voting to leave closed since whilst this is now a clear and well-worded question I think it's still off-topic for this site: its about measuring computational speed, albeit the speed of a cryptographic algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\displaystyle \text{cycles per byte} = \frac{\text{cycles per second}}{\text{bytes per second}} = \frac{2.1 ~ \text{GHz}}{4.3 ~ \text{MiB}} = \frac{2.1 \times 10^9}{4.3 \times 1024^2} \approx 466 ~ \text{cpb}$

---

Of course this may be way off because processors are complex beasts these days, and may not work at their full potential all the time, and the calculations may very well be reordered, optimized, or vectorized.

So it's a little better than raw speed in that it is not dependent of processor clock speed but it is still quite dependent on the underlying hardware details. It is a decent measure of cryptographic performance.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I do not understand why data i see are very different ... for example this report fastcrypto.org/umac/2004/perf04.html cycles per byte are much less, why?

Comment: @LucaDelGiudice Maybe the algorithm you are using has not been optimized during compilation, which would explain the slow speeds you see. But without additional details it's hard to tell.

Comment: @LucaDelGiudice Just noticed the "hash" tag. If you are measuring the performance of a hash function, you want to use messages longer than 16 bytes, otherwise most of the time will be spend doing initialization/finalization work (which do take up a lot of clock cycles for most hash functions). Try a 32MB buffer, you should see better results.